# infinite jQuery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I plan to use some music on my site, but before I make it autoplay for each visitor, I would like to have either an alert pop up immediately, asking if they would like the music to play, or a nice little tooltip of some sort to present a message stating that you can check whether or not you would like the music.

So, I know I can set a cookie via the [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) but I was wondering if I could set the cookie's time to infinite, in other words, never to delete it, unless the end-user deletes all of their cookies, or the specific one for my site.

Is this not considered a valid use of cookies?  If not, for a task like this, what should time do you suggest I set it to?

Comment: Bad idea, music doesn't belong on websites, and the only thing more annoying would be bothering people with a popup before playing music.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like 10 years is infinite enough for this ever-changing web realm ;)

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 365 * 10 });
```

Comment: I don't know, they remember my site after 10 years, and want to come back! :D OK, thanks!

Comment: @Azimuth, yeah .. it's been 7 years and yet we are (or at least I am) still here on stackoverflow .. maybe after 3 more years I'd edit my answer to 100 years or something :P